# Websockets stopped working after adding nginx and gunicorn

Tags: nginx, websocket, gunicorn, nginx-reverse-proxy, django-channels

I am making a django-react app, and I use django channels for my websockets in order to create live chat. After adding gunicorn and nginx however, my websockets are no longer able to connect from my frontend and I am not sure if I have the right nginx configuration.

My `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /app/staticfiles/;
    }
}
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /usr/src/referralhub
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev libssl-dev
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /tmp/requirements.txt && rm -rf /tmp/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip install gunicorn
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "referralhub.wsgi:application"]
```

My `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.9.18"

services:
  django:
    build: .
    container_name: django
    command: gunicorn referralhub.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}

    depends_on:
      - redis

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
    depends_on:
      - django

volumes:
  static_volume:
```

My `asgi.py`:

```
"""
ASGI config for referralhub project.

It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/asgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
import backend.routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'referralhub.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            backend.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    )
})
```

some of my `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'channels',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'backend',
    'corsheaders',
]
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'referralhub.asgi.application'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("redis", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```